# ¿Cómo Gráfico los datos de mi consulta desde Laravel con vue?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, chart.js

Cómo puedo pasar estos datos  para que puedan ser graficados

```html
[
  {
    "Ncantidad": 7,
    "categoria_id": 3,
    "categoria": {
      "id": 3,
      "nombre": "test3"
    }
  },
  {
    "Ncantidad": 5,
    "categoria_id": 2,
    "categoria": {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "test2"
    }
  }
]
```

Necesito pasarle de manera dinamica segun la cantidad de elementos donde dice series : Data, tengo que pasarle  el valor de la variable **Ncantidad** Y donde dice categories pasar el nombre del categoría.

```html
export default {

    components: {
      apexcharts: VueApexCharts,
    },
    props:['graficar'],
    data: function() {
      return {
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            id: 'vuechart-example'
          },
          xaxis: {

             categories: [1182, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998]
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'preguntas',
          data: [54, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]

        }]
      }
    },
};
```

he intentado como dije antes, pasarle una variable directa,pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu pregunta no explicas de donde sale el array de datos, así que voy a suponer que se lo pasas al componente mediante props (en `graficar`).

Por otro lado, dado que dices que

> donde dice 
>   series : Data, tengo que pasarle el valor de la variable Ncantidad 
>   Y donde dice categories pasar el nombre del categoría.

entiendo que quieres llegar a que `chartOptions` sea

```
chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        id: 'vuechart-example'
      },
      xaxis: {

            categories: ['test3', 'test2']
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'preguntas',
      data: [7, 5]

    }]
```

En ese caso, `chartOptions` no debiese estar en `data` sino que debiera ser `computed`

```
export default {

  components: {
    apexcharts: VueApexCharts,
  },
  props: ['graficar'],

  computed: {

    chartOptions() {
      return {
        chart: {
          id: 'vuechart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {

          categories: this.graficar.map((item)=>{
            return item.categoria.nombre
          })
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'preguntas',
        data: this.graficar.map((item)=>{
            return item.Ncantidad;
          })

      }]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Igual intente meterlo en cumputed. pero no me deja, Pero de igual forma hice lo  que pusiste y ahora Todo funciona. Solo una pregunta. 

¿cómo se llama este tipo de recorrido o que dato es? 
categories: this.graficar.map((item)=>{
            return item.categoria.nombre
          })
para  que busque más acerca.

Comment: El método map es nativo de cualquier array. Es lo mismo que haber puesto `this.graficar.map(function(item) { return item.categoria.nombre });`  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

En Vue el objeto `this` siempre es el componente mismo, y puedes acceder a sus propiedades, data, computed properties y métodos indistintamente